# cyclic subgroups and generators

Tags: group-theory

> g is a generator of the cyclic group C45. Sketch the lattice of
>   subgroups of $C_{45} $ For each subgroup, state its order and give a
>   generator in terms of g. You do NOT need to list the elements of the
>   subgroups.

I know that each generator of the group  has an order that is a divisor of 45,

so all divisors in c_{45} are 1 , 3 ,5 ,9 , 15 ,45

I dont understand how to draw the lattice?

which is :

[image]

Can someone please explain this picture to me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The lattice gives you all subgroups of $C_{45}$ and their pairwise subgroup relationships. A line connecting two groups means the bottom-most group is a subgroup of the top-most one (and there isn't one "in between"). So $C_3$ is subgroup of $C_9$ and $C_{15}$ (and therefore of $C_{45}$), but not of $C_5$. There is a path from group $H$ to group $G$ only going upward if and only if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

For a finite cyclic group $G = \langle g \rangle$ of order $n$, we can find all subgroups by looking at the divisors of $n$. For every $d \;\vert\; n$ we have $H = \langle g^{d} \rangle$ is a cyclic subgroup of order $\frac{n}{d}$ (so isomorphic to $C_{n/d}$).

Hence, to draw the lattice yourself, look at the divisors of $n = 45$. Each of them will give you a subgroup. Note that since all subgroups are also cyclic, if we have $k \;\vert\; d \;\vert\; n$ then $\langle g^d \rangle \subset \langle g^k \rangle \subset \langle g \rangle$ is a tower of subgroups. To see which lines to connect to $G$, we want the prime divisors $d$ of $n$. Otherwise, as we just saw there will be another subgroup in between $\langle g^d \rangle$ and $G$. You can then repeat this procedure for the other subgroups, or alternatively for a subgroup $\langle g^d \rangle$ look at the divisors $d' \;\vert\; n$ that add one prime factor to $d$, i.e. $d' = d \cdot p$. All such $\langle g^{d'} \rangle$ will be the "immediate" subgroups (hence neighbours in the lattice) of $\langle g^d \rangle$.

Comment: what does this mean   $ {g^{15}}  \cong C_{3] $?

Comment: $\langle g^{15} \rangle$ denotes the subgroup that is generated by the element $g^{15}$. So $\langle g^{15} \rangle = \{g^{15}, (g^{15})^2, (g^{15})^3 = e\} \cong C_3$.

Comment: sorry I know what <g^{15}> is, why is it isomorphic to C3? thats what I meant. Thank you.

Comment: Because it's a cyclic group of order 3 :) I listed the elements for you, you should be able to write a direct correspondence of each of the three elements with the elements you know of $C_3$ and see they behave identically.

Comment: Note that this is because for $a \;|\; \mathrm{ord}(g)$ we have $\mathrm{ord}(g^a) = \frac{\mathrm{ord}(g)}{a}$, and if we have a generator $g$ of a cyclic group $G$ then $|G| = \mathrm{ord}(g)$.

Comment: Okay I see what you mean. However is there a 'short cut' method to work out what each subgroup is isomorphic to ? for example to know <g^3> is isomorphic to c15 , would i have to continue with power of <g^{3> until i get the identity, which is 15 times ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24883/discussion-between-italy-and-mark).